# How to access methods of openlayers map in vue3

Tags: vue.js, openlayers, vuejs3, openlayers-3, vue3-openlayers

I use [vue3-openlyers](https://github.com/MelihAltintas/vue3-openlayers) to create a map like the following:

```xml
<ol-map ref="map">
...
</ol-map>
```

In Vue's composition api, I try to access the `getSize()` method of the map:

```js
import { ref, defineComponent, onMounted } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
    setup() {
        //works with views
        const map = ref<any>(null);

        const getSize = () => {
            // does not work
            console.log(map.value.getSize());
            console.log(map.getSize());
        };

        onMounted(getSize());
    
        return { map, getSize }
});
```

I get the following error:
`TypeError: map.value is null`

I suspect that the map variable is not updating. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Maybe I don´t understand the syntax, but if you call `getSize()`, what do you expect to happen, if there is only a console output?

Comment: getSize() should return the size of the map container. So it should just output the container size.

Comment: But in your example, the only actions taken in `getSize` are `console.log(map.value.getSize())` and `console.log(map.getSize())`?

Comment: I don't think if I understand your question, but the only purpose of getSize is to ouput the size of the map on the console. It should not return anything, it is just there to confirm that map.getSize() works.

Comment: Okay. Have you tried to output `map` on console? `map.value` is null, according to the error.

Answer (score 5):

You can call the methods of the referenced map using `this.$refs.map.map.<method>`.
(`this` cannot be accessed inside the composition api!! Use it in e. g. `mounted()`).

For example you can get the size of the map:
`this.$refs.map.map.getSize()`